# Posso colocar duas condições/incrementos dentro do mesmo laço?

Tags: java, sintaxe, for

Quero, basicamente, fazer isso

```
for (j = parametro, int k=0; j < parametro + 3, k<3; j++, k++) {
    previsoes[i] += valores[j] * pesos[k] ;
}
```

Comment: Você estragou minha piadinha, brother =/

Comment: De qualquer forma, espero que minha resposta tenha te ajudado

Comment: Ajudou muito, obrigado!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pode.

Note que depois da primeira declaração você não precisa especificar o tipo. O incremento está correto. Aproveitei e adicionei um exemplo de como colocar "duas condições".

Assim:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < 10 && k < 3; i++, k++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(k);
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>**[Veja funcionando no Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/CumbersomeGoodZebu)**</sup>

Comment: Boa! +1! Só um detalhe: não é que ele não _precisa_ especificar o tipo da segunda variável. Ele **não pode** especificar o tipo da segunda variável (mesmo que seja o mesmo tipo que a primeira). É como se você declarasse dois atributos da classe separados com vírgula. Isso só funciona se os atributos forem do mesmo tipo.

Comment: @IgorVenturelli Sim, é porque só é possível adicionar um _statement_ de uma linha. Vou deixar isso mais claro. Agradeço o feedback